# Color movie from the '50s or early '60s about an Earth crew visiting a women's planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

There were officers like in *Star Trek: The Original Series*: captain, another officer, a doctor named Bones.

The women did not mingle with the Earthmen at first, so one of them tried a joke about arched legs and his target became indignant.

The ending was like *Total Recall* (1990): they created an atmosphere for the planet.

I watched it in color around 1960 in a movie theater, and then again in the eighties on cbc tv in Montreal.

---

It's not *Queen of Outer Space* or *World Without End*.

Comment: Did you watch this in the '50s or '60s, or later? If later, then when, roughly? Also, was this black white or in colour?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSuhi1o_9Cs

Comment: I watched it in color around 1960 in a movie theater, and then again in the eighties on cbc tv in Montreal.

Answer (score 10):

Possibly *[Queen of Outer Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_Outer_Space)* (1958), starring Zsa Zsa Gabor as the Hitlerish Queen of Venus, where the men have been overthrown and packed off to detention camps.  She tries to destroy Earth with a disintegrator, but of course is duly thwarted. The Earth astronauts who are stranded there manage to overthrow her in the nick of time with the aid of local dissidents. I recall watching it as a 10 year old. It was in colour.

Comment: I know that movie, I have watched it in this century, and it's not the one I have in mind, sorry. I forgot to mention that mine is also in color. I am going to edit my question. Mine, as can be seen, does not conform to today's morals, that's probably why it is beeing hidden from the public.

Comment: That's unlikely. A lot of these older films go against current mores and are not hidden in the least.

Comment: You might be right. All I can say is that it's a nice movie and I have been in the lookout for it since the eighties.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely "World Without End" (Allied Artists 1956) Directed by Edward Bernds.Some of your recollections match this film plot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this matches the question?

Comment: I watched a couple of clips of "World without end, 1956" on youtube and it's not it. This one I didn't know, thank you. PS: And mine is not a horror movie. And it's an american movie.